# What episodes in TNG contain the Ferengi?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, suggested-order

I'm re-watching Star Trek TNG episodes to get a better understanding of how the Ferengi have evolved over the years, into what they are now known as in DS9.

Irrespective of how accurate the depiction is to their later depiction, what episodes in TNG contain any sort of reference to or interaction with the Ferengi?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Ferengi make an appearance in the following TNG episodes:

- **Season 1**

"The Last Outpost"
"The Battle"

- **Season 2**

"Peak Performance"

- **Season 3**

"The Price"
"Captain's Holiday"
"Ménage à Troi"

- **Season 4**

"Future Imperfect" (Hologram Only)

- **Season 5**

"Unification II"
"The Perfect Mate"

- **Season 6**

"Rascals"
"Chain of Command, Part I"
"Suspicions"

- **Season 7**

"Force of Nature"
"Firstborn"
"Bloodlines"

They also receive a substantial mention in "Encounter at Farpoint, Part I"

You can find a complete list of **all** appearances in the various Star Trek TV series [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ferengi#Appearances) and their appearances in the EU novels and comics [here](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Ferengi).

Comment: Well found and well shared.  Thank you.